# Is it possible to abort a synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, blob

I am experimenting to download data from an online radio live stream with `XMLHttpRequest` to a Blob. At first I tried async requests with passing the last option as `true`. Then I tried the synchronous method, which in fact froze the page, because the data never arrives fully, thanks to the live audio stream infinite nature. I can't abort it by pressing `Ctrl+C` and I even can't close the page. Can I somehow abort it? Unfortunately I didn't pass a time-out data.

Comment: No...need to close whole browser from OS  or worst case reboot computer. Synchronous requests block everything and should never be used

Comment: Thx, finally I had to use: pgrep -f "/opt/google/chrome/chrome"|ruby -e 'STDIN.read.split("\n").each{|p| system %Q{kill -9 #{p}}}'
To kill the numerous browser instances.